# Join table on itself in Adonis.js Query Builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I have a `mssql` table that stores employee information include the key for their manager. In `sql` this is easy enough to join on itself and get the manager's name with the employee record. I am trying to find a way to do this in adonis using the lucid query builder. The code I have currently is

```
const employees = await Database.from('Employees').orderBy('EmployeeName', 'asc')
```

Adonis has an innerJoin method but since the tables are the same I am not sure how to differentiate them in the join.

```
.innerJoin('Employees', 'Employees.id', 'Employees.manager_id')
```

so the full code would be something like

```
const employees = await Database.from('Employees')
.innerJoin('Employees', 'Employees.id', 'Employees.manager_id')
.orderBy('EmployeeName', 'asc')
```

This could be done easily just running raw `sql` in the app, but I would like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: You can make use of Adonis Lucid models, it's easier that way

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

```
const employees = await Database.from('Employees as a')
.innerJoin('Employees as b', 'a.id', 'b.manager_id')
.orderBy('EmployeeName', 'asc')
```